# How to use a property from UserControl in T-SQL query

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, properties

I have an UserControl I call and I want to use a property defined in the code behind in the Sqldatasource query in the front to get a certain selection of rows. I can't find anything related on Google/SO can anyone help me?

Code behind:

```
Public Sub Show(ByVal Contacts_ID As String)

End Sub
```

Code in the .ASCX:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Cnt%>"
          SelectCommand="QUERYstring + Contacts_ID">
          <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Companies_ID" SessionField="Companies_ID" />
          </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

EDIT: Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it in a session:

```
Public Sub Show(ByVal Contacts_ID As String)
    Session("Contacts_ID") = Contacts_ID
End Sub
```

Then use it like your other session variable in user control:

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Cnt%>" SelectCommand="YourStoredProcedure" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
      <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="Companies_ID" SessionField="Companies_ID" />
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="Contacts_ID" SessionField="Contacts_ID" />
      </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**NOTE**: I have used a stored procedure in my example which is the better way to pass parameters than a query string